How to re-define PYTHONPATH --completely-- in Visual Studio Code
I need to re-define the PYTHONPATH within Visual Studio Code (VSC) without it inheriting any values from the default PYTHONPATH set in my shell (zsh).
System Information:
macOS: Sonoma 14.6.1,
Visual Studio Code: 1.94.0,
Python Extension: v2024.16.1,
Shell: zsh
Steps I’ve Taken:

Created a dev.env file in my workspace.
Added the following line in dev.env to set the PYTHONPATH: 
PYTHONPATH="/Users/me/project/utils"
Referenced this file in my .code-workspace file as follows:
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/dev.env"

Problem: The PYTHONPATH is being modified instead of being set entirely re-defined by the value in the dev.env file.
It starts with the path I defined in dev.env, but it also appends the default PYTHONPATH from my shell. But I need it to replace the PYTHONPATH instead of modifying it.
Additional Attempt: I tried to reset the PYTHONPATH using the following config definition:
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
   "PYTHONPATH": null
}

I tried this config in config files/setting below:

~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json

${workspaceFolder}my_workspace.code-workspace


But this doesn't work either.
Expected Result: I want to ensure that Visual Studio Code uses only the PYTHONPATH specified in the dev.env file, without inheriting or appending values from the shell environment.
Any idea what else I can do?
THX

open a terminal, delete the PYTHONPATH variable, start VSC FROM terminal with code .

If you prefer switching to another terminal different from the integrated one(so it won't conflict with environmental variable in your default shell), you may check this out: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles
